# According to the Young Earth Creationism, why there is still the darkness after God created the light and what does it mean Gen 1:4?

Tags: genesis, young-earth-creation

Genesis 1:4

> God saw that the light was good, and **He separated the light from the
> darkness**

There is an empty room with a 1000 watt light bulb which is off 
if someone turn on that light from outside the room, 
there won't be any darkness in that room.
Hence the question : why there is still the darkness after God created the light?

There is a black paper.
Someone sprinkle some white rubber paint on that black paper.
Now the paper has a white spot here and there.
Then this someone **separate the white from the black**.
So now on the paper there is a side which all white and another side which all black.

Hence the question is : 
*what does it mean Genesis 1:4 ?*

This question is answered in this [link](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/84617/according-to-the-young-earth-creationism-what-does-it-mean-genesis-114-and-18/84622#84622).
The answer describes that *He separated the light from the darkness* **is not an act of God**. It's just the writer story telling style that the creation of light is causing the separation of the light from the darkness.

Comment: For the same reason there is still fire after the creation of water, or water after the creation of dry land, or good and evil existing within the same world, etc.

Comment: This separation in Genesis 1 is primarily temporal, a period of light and a period of darkness, together forming one day.

Comment: @curiousdannii, I'm still searching in the internet what about earth rotation according to the YEC. Verse 5 _God called the light “day,” and the darkness he called “night.” And there was evening, AND there was morning_ . To me it's a very difficult sentence to grasp. Does it mean "this part of earth which is bright called "day" and that another part of the earth which is dark called "night" ? or does it mean "and there was evening, THEN there was morning" ?

Comment: @karma As described in [my answer to your other question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/84620/10672) Young Earth Creationists have a lot of flexibility in imagining what it was like while being faithful to the Bible.  Don't limit yourself to a false dilemma that you created.  The historical survey of Young Earth positions by prominent early church fathers should broaden our horizon to many Biblical possibilities.

Comment: Perhaps there was light everywhere that abruptly ceased. Perhaps it was gathered to all emanate from a single point that would later become the Sun, such that part of the Earth was then in its own shadow. We don't know.

Comment: Let's try this: Edit your title.  put some effort into it.  Make it clear and succinct.  That's on you, the question asker.  Sloppy work isn't good for this site.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> There is an empty room with a 1000 watt light bulb which is off
> if someone turn on that light from outside the room,
> there won't be any darkness in that room.

We don't have to conceive the light and the earth in Gen 1:3-5 that way.  The historical survey of Young Earth positions by prominent early church fathers should broaden our horizon to many Biblical possibilities.  This answer is based on Ken Ham's hypothesis described in my answer to your other question [According to the Young Earth Creationism, how is the whole earth globe after the creation of the light?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/84620/10672):

> The first three days are written the same way as the next three. So if we let the language speak to us, all six days were ordinary earth days. . . . The sun is not needed for day and night. What is needed is light and a rotating earth. On the first day of creation, God made light (Genesis 1:3).
>
> The phrase “evening and morning” certainly implies a rotating earth. Thus, if we have light from one direction, and a spinning earth, there can be day and night.

*Source*: [Light Before the Sun: How biblical apologists have historically understood the source of light before the sun was created in Genesis 1](https://answersingenesis.org/days-of-creation/days-without-sun-what-was-source-light/)

If we conceive the "light" in Gen 1:1-3 as *temporary lighting of the earth* placed similar to where our sun currently is (i.e. shining on earth from one direction) then it's quite straightforward to interpret Gen 1:4 as follows:

> In Genesis 1:3–5, we are greeted with light. According to most commentators, the light was either created by God or manifested by himself. This light separated the darkness, was observed by God as being “good” and was called “day” while the darkness was called “night.” Together they made up the first evening and morning of day 1 of creation week.

For full details, please see my answer to your other question [According to the Young Earth Creationism, what does it mean Genesis 1:14 and 18?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/84622/10672)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, GratefulDisciple. But I'm sorry, the thing which I can't understand is the act of God on verse 4. Based on my empty room with a light bulb illustration, it leads to a conclusion that after the creation of light, the whole globe surface is bright. Continuing the illustration, starting from the point where the whole room is bright, that someone do another thing which causing some part of the room is dark another part is bright ---> this is the act of the separation of the light from the darkness.

Comment: Similar illustration, but there is a solid ball in that room and the light bulb are everywhere, so rays is coming from everywhere. So, there is no part of the ball which is dark. Later on, if that someone do something to those light-bulbs which causing there is a part of the ball which is dark ---> then his act can be called as "separating the light from the darkness".,

Comment: @karma Please see [my answer to your other question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/84622/10672), which has a lot more detail to show how there is still darkness if the created light in v. 3 is placed in a certain way.