# According to the Young Earth Creationism, how is the whole earth globe after the creation of the light?

Tags: creation, young-earth-creation

As we all know, when there is one light source - any solid sphere shape will have part of its surface dark - because the light rays is in one direction.

So the question is :
how is the whole earth globe after the creation of the light ?
(A) the whole surface of the earth is bright or 
(B) there is a part of its surface which is dark.

This question is started because I can't understand how was the event when *"then He separated the light from the darkness"* (Gen 1:4b) where I also make a question about this in [this link](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/84613/according-to-the-young-earth-creationism-why-there-is-still-the-darkness-after/84621#84621) and [this link](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/236048?noredirect=1).

I am reading the sentence of Gen 1:4b at face value, so to me it tells an act which is proceed after the act of creating the light in Gen 1:3. Consequently, myself answer is point-A.

So my problem is :
If the answer is point-B (which in other words, once the light was created - the light and the darkness is already separated "automatically") then how was the event when *"then He separated the light from the darkness"*? what does it mean ? ---> as asked in [this link](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/84613/according-to-the-young-earth-creationism-why-there-is-still-the-darkness-after/84621#84621) and [this link](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/236048?noredirect=1).

Anyway, this question is answered on another of my question in [this link](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/236048?noredirect=1), where the answer in short is "*the writer of Genesis did not mean the sentence of Gen 1:4b at face value*".

Comment: The spherical shape generates the time zones, but what you wrote is nonsense; regardless of shape, unless the earth were transparent, there would still be dark and luminous zones, were there to be only one (meaningful) light-source (a detail absent from Genesis).

Comment: That's the point, Lucian. So if YEC teaching that there is a part of the earth surface dark once after the light created, then the words _"and there was evening, and there was morning"_ can be mean at the same time, where one part of the earth is evening at the same time another part of the earth is morning.

Comment: **Me:** *What you wrote is nonsense.* **You:** *That's the point.* **Me (again):** I'm kind of lost here.

Comment: You say that after the light created : _there would still be dark and luminous zones_, **me:** then the light and the darkness is separated once the light created. So what does it mean : _and He separated the light from the darkness_ ?

Comment: It means that they are separate (day from night, evening and morning).

Comment: What I mean is, IF the answer that the whole surface of the earth are bright once the light created, then it still can be grasped if later on God "separate the light from the darkness" which causing one part of the globe dark - one part of the globe bright. As in my other post's illustration, if that someone pour the white paint to all the surface of that black paper, then it still can be grasped if later on someone told me "then he separate the white from the black" which cause one part of the paper all black and other part all white.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast, I've edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: thanks, appreciate the effort

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based on a 2019 article [Light Before the Sun: How biblical apologists have historically understood the source of light before the sun was created in Genesis 1](https://answersingenesis.org/days-of-creation/days-without-sun-what-was-source-light/) by authors speaking on behalf of a premier Young Earth Creationist institution: [Answers in Genesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answers_in_Genesis).

The article presents several Young Earth Creationist views that have been held in the past (along with their weaknesses) then presents Ken Ham's view as one possibility (Ken Ham is co-founder and CEO of Answers in Genesis):

- **Tertullian** (155-220 AD) : the light was a physical manifestation of Christ's glory in creation week, 4 millenia before the Incarnation, based on John 1:9
- **Ephrem the Syrian** (306-373 AD) : Pillar of fire that later became the sun
- **Basil of Caesarea** (329-379 AD) : God created the essence of the sun from days 1-3 and put it in the "lamp" of the sun on day 4, likening it to the burning bush (fire was not really burning from the bush)
- **Augustine of Hippo** (354-430 AD) : Angels as Luminaries provide the light (Job 38:7, Ps 104:4, Acts 12:7, Rev 12:9)
- **Rabbinic Judaism view** in *Midrash Bereishit Rabbah* (completed c. 500 AD) : God's *Shekinah* glory (Ex 40:34, 2 Chron 7:1-2, Eze 43:2, Ps 104:2)
- **Matthew Poole** (1624-1679 AD): bright cloud which moved across the earth, later repurposed as the sun on the 4th day
- **Dr. John Whitcom** (1924-2020 AD): proto-sun which was done away with once God created the sun on day 4
- **Ken Ham** (1951- AD): doesn't take a position, but states that it must be a light source which shone on a rotating earth once the light and darkness were separated to functionally serve the same purpose as the later-created sun

The article then states how Young Earth Creationists are open to multiple hypotheses:

> As can be seen from the small sampling above, there are numerous views on this subject, and all of them are based on accepting the Bible as the ultimate authority and then using theological inference from Scripture alone to develop an explanation for that which Scripture does not specifically state. Ultimately, we must admit that Scripture doesn’t satisfy our curiosity on this question, but leaves us free to put forth possible explanations, as long as we acknowledge that we cannot dogmatically assert our favored hypothesis as “fact.”

The article concludes with several guidelines to forming a Biblical hypothesis:

- That the light is a *created light* from a source(s) that no longer exists
- That we shouldn't mix the prophetic language in Revelation to interpret historical narrative in Genesis
- That we shouldn't limit our understanding of how when God first created light, it lit up everything, recalling 2 Cor 4:6

#### Conclusion

Answering your question:

> How is the whole earth globe after the creation of the light? Is the whole surface of the earth bright, or there is a part of its surface which is dark?

I think it's safe to say that the earth is **already a rotating globe** before Gen 1:3, and that the light shining on it came from *heaven*, which already exists since Gen 1:1.  Like "a light from heaven shone around" Paul/Saul on the road to Damascus (Acts 9:3), this light can be from a *physical* heaven (i.e., sky) or from *spiritual* heaven (i.e. God's Throne Room).

Quotes from [Chapter 8](https://answersingenesis.org/days-of-creation/could-god-really-have-created-everything-in-six-days/) of Ken Ham's 2016 book [The New Answers Book 1: Over 25 Questions on Creation/Evolution and the Bible](https://answersingenesis.org/answers/books/new-answers-book-1/):

> The first three days are written the same way as the next three. So if we let the language speak to us, all six days were ordinary earth days. . . . The sun is not needed for day and night. What is needed is light and a rotating earth. On the first day of creation, God made light (Genesis 1:3).
>
> The phrase “evening and morning” certainly implies a rotating earth. Thus, if we have light from one direction, and a spinning earth, there can be day and night.
>
> Some people ask why God did not tell us the source of this light. However, if God told us everything, we would have so many books we would not have time to read them. God has given us all the information we need to come to the right conclusions about the things that really matter.

Comment: The Creation Ministries International (the parent organisation of AiG, before the split) logo was actually designed to represent this: https://creation.com/our-logo

Comment: Thank you very much for the detail explanation, GratefulDisciple. The thing which I still don't understand is, the verse say another act of God after the light created. Verse 3 : God create the light.... verse 4 : And God saw that the light was good. *THEN he separated the light from the darkness*. As my last comment respond to Lucian, based on my illustration, it can be grasped if later on someone tell me _"THEN he separate the white from the black"_ as the condition before the act of separation, **the whole black paper is white**. (continue)

Comment: If based on the illustration, so to understand verse 4, then the conclusion about the condition before the act of separation by God  : **the whole earth globe is bright** (all earth's surface get the light rays created in verse 3).

Comment: @karma, God Created Light. And photons were everywhere and traveling in all directions, and God said "this won't do", and so he eliminated all of them except those traveling in (perhaps more or less) *one* direction, thus "separating" light from darkness... Really, we don't know. (The preceding, in case it wasn't obvious, is speculative as all else.)

Comment: @karma I answered all your questions in my [answer to your other question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/84622/10672)

Comment: @curiousdannii, thanks for the reference. The logo has "black (on the left) - white (on the center) - black (on the right)". While my guess for the left-black and center-white represents earth's night and day, I'm curious what is the black on the right represent to them ?

Comment: The right half is the earth in light against the background of blackness.